# resource route with default parameter instead :id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I have a route for one of my resources:

```
resources :categories
```

and I need to generate link to category with `key` property instead of `id` so I use this:

```
category_path(category, :id=>category.key)
```

which generates this

```
/categories/blah.1
```

where `blah` is desired key and `1` is undesired id. How can I awoid that dot with id any why it appears there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to fix it permanently, which doesn't require you to have `category_path(category, :id=>category.key)` all the places in your views is that you can create an instance method in your `Category` class(*app/models/category.rb*):

```
def to_param
  key.try(:parameterize)
end
```

Basically, [`to_param`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param) is the method which is called in Rails at the time of generating a model object to URL. We've just overridden it here. Now, you don't have to write `category_path(...)`, you can just do:

```
<%= link_to category.name, category %>
```

and it'll use `key` by default. Change `category.name` with your appropriate value which you want to show in the link, it was just an example.

Note: Make sure you always validate `key` attribute to be present and unique in your `Category` class, so that you don't run into invalid/no category being found in the controller at the time of find query.